# Seeking free application or web service for reverse geocoding

Tags: data, software-recommendations, reverse-geocoding, service-recommendations

I'm looking for a fast and free web service or local application (this it would be better, a local service with database of street, numbers, city, etc.) for reverse geocoding.

I could use google but is limited to 5000 query per day...

What I m trying to do is convert positions acquired from a gps (1 per second) in addresses. These positions could be more than 7000 per track, and if I have 10 track for example, the mole of data to "translate" becames "huge"..

Answer (score 4):

You will find free geocoding services limited (in quailty) but commercial geocoders (Google Enterprise, Yahoo JBoss, TomTom) good quality but expensive for number of requests over 100,000+

> Geocoding is the process of matching addresses with geographic
>   coordinates.  The MapQuest Open Geocoding API designed to provide an
>   easier way to geocode using OpenStreetMap (OSM) data.  The Open
>   Geocoding API is based on Nominatim and supports three major geocoding
>   functions: address, reverse, and batch.  There is no app key required
>   to use this service.

In your case I would recommend **MapQuest Open Geocoding Service**

MapQuest have an open geocoding api (based from data from OpenStreetMap)

To do a reverse geocode you need to sign up [Free] for an api key.
The you can send requests like

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=renderReverse&location=40.0755,-76.329999
```

for JSON response simply add `&json={location:{latLng:{` to the call

```
http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&callback=renderReverse&json={location:{latLng:{lat:40.0755,lng:-76.329999}}}
```

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/geocoding-service

Resverse Geocoding Examples (as above)

http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reverse

if your a coder then see

http://open.mapquestapi.com/media/js/samples/geocoding/reverse.js

Comment: Interesting service, but I don't know how much complete is OSM in Italy... I could try..
What I m trying to do is convert positions acquired from a gps (1 per second) in addresses. These positions could be more than 7000 per track, and if I have 10 track for example, the mole of data to "translate" becames "huge"..

Ps. all sorry for my english.. i'm trying to learn also that ;)

Comment: @crc_error can you add that valuable information to your question please.

Comment: Italy is quite well covered for OpenStreetMap - http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=43.58&lon=15.46&zoom=6&layers=M

Comment: There is a 15,000/month limit now https://developer.mapquest.com/plans

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) for reverse geocoding.

You can find information about the use of webservices here: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Answer (score 0):

[Geocode.Farm](https://geocode.farm) provides an inexpensive API that does reverse geocoding. Can't go wrong. You can use it for both forward and reverse requests and get results in jSON or XML. Results are very accurate.

UPDATE: This API actually provides free usage, read their documentation page. It is not only a PAID API.

Comment: OP asked for free, not inexpensive